# What do you think about the B-Twin bicycles? Is it better to buy a new B-Twin or an used bike by a more famous brand?

Tags: mountain-bike, used-bike

I was in a sports store the other day I've felt in love with this bike http://www.btwincycle.com/EN/rockrider-5-1-c1-2011-170478654/ What do you guys think? I'm gonna ride it mostly in the city, and I don't really like city bikes. And, I'm looking for a bike under 250 $.

Should I buy it or not?

Comment: They appear to achieve the low price in part by using plain steel components in places where better bikes would be aluminum or stainless steel.  This would not be a bike that should be left out in the weather.  (Have you considered buying a used bike?)

Comment: I thought of that... and I found this one (actually new) http://www.dunlopbikes.com/dunlop-special-edition-26-inch-939057... and this one uses steel as well...

Answer (score 1):

This question is too subjective to answer well, but here's a few things to think over.

A used bike can appear to be in great shape, and still require a large amount of work and money to put right. If you don't know much about the mechanical side of cycling, I always recommend buying new, from a local bike shop you trust, that services their own bikes.

Size is very personal and very specific. Used bikes can fit well, but you need good advice about what fits you, and what doesn't and why. That can be difficult to get from a person selling a bike when they only have one size.

A new, but very basic bike, like the one listed above, can be a very short term purchase, if you get into cycling, and you may need or want to replace it in less than one year. It may be worthwhile to wait a bit longer, save a bit more money, and get a bike which will last you 2-3 years, before you will outgrow it.

Again, I always recommend you buy the best bike that you can afford. You won't regret it, and it makes it more likely you will enjoy the sport.